# GraphQL Spring-boot Query filtering

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I'm using the GraphQL Spring-boot library to build a GraphQL API
https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-spring-boot

I have a schema

```
type Car {
    id: ID!
    model: String
    brand: String
}

type Query {
    allCars: [Car]!
}
```

And my query is implemented in a Query class in my Spring Boot project

```
@Component
public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

public List<Machine> allCars() {}

}
```

My question is:

How do I use filters and sorting when returning lists:

```
allCars(first:3){id model}

allCars(filter: {....}){}
```

I guess this is something that has to be implemented in the Java method, but i'm unsure how to inject the filters etc. in the method.

Comment: Have you been able to find something that auto-generates the filters for every model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that you would create your own filter input type, for example:

```graphql
type Query {
    allCars(filter: CarsFilter!): [Car]
}


input CarsFilter {
    color: String!
    brand: String!
}
```

After that, you can write a Java implementation of `CarsFilter`, for example:

```java
public class CarsFilter {
    private String color;
    private String brand;

    // Getters + Setters
}
```

Now you can write your resolver using the `CarsFilter` class:

```
public List<Car> allCars(CarsFilter filter) {
    // Filter by using JPA specifications, custom queries, ...
}
```

Comment: Ok - that would make sense. 
I was wondering if there were some filtering and sorting available as part of the GraphQL Java library. Since we can restrict return parameters from our "types/models"

Answer (score 2):

GraphQL allows for the client to specify exactly what data is desired but it doesn't has any inbuilt way of filtering and sorting the data. You will have write code for that yourself. Regarding injecting the filters, one possible way of doing it can be following:

```
type Query {
    allCars(filter: String, range: String, sort: String): [Car]!
}
```

For above Query, sample request would be like:

```
{
    allCars(filter: "{brand: 'Abc'}", range: "[0, 100]", sort: "[id, ASC]") { # Fetch first 100 cars of brand 'Abc' sorted by id
        id
        model
        brand
    }
}
```

Then your getAllCars method would be like following:

```
public List<Car> getAllCars(String filter, String range, String sort) {
    // Implement parser and filter by using JPA specifications
}
```

To see a sample implementation of parser and its conversion it to JPA specifications, please refer to following project: https://github.com/jaskaransingh156/spring-boot-graphql-with-custom-rql

Comment: Hi Jaskaran, I was looking at your blog and tried to implement with Spring boot 3.1.x and Spring boot data jpa 3.1.x. But I was getting an error for 
FilterService required a single bean, but 2(my no. of repos extending base repo) were found

so do you have any workaround for this for newer version of Spring boot.